# Rails: bad idea: manually creating a session cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session, cookies

The 'CTO' of my company thinks it's a good idea to handle authentication by manually creating a cookie.

Can someone please help me explain what a bad idea this is.

Comment: Why you think it's a bad idea? And what is your solution?

Comment: You use HTTPS and http-only cookies (i.e., the built in session). End of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas. Although I'm not convinced that it's completely off the wall.

- Reinventing The Wheel - what benefit does home grown give you, rails
  should be faster to implement.
- Potential for making a trivial
  mistake (not random..enough, too short    value etc)  which exposes a
  vulnerability
- Lack of portability - switching storage in rails
  to queue, or db etc.is a config change
- Need to implement reset_session
- Need to implement session expiry
- You'll probably be setting a session cookie anyways, unless you turn    it off
- A lot of people care about rails session security, it's going to be
  maintained..

Actually, changed my mind. It is a dumb idea.